# using multiple statements to get the id from another table

Tags: php, sql, database

I am quite new to programming and am having some problems in trying to get data from a SQL database into my PHP website.
I will make something quite similar to the scenario below.

Let's say my tables include:

pets

```
pet_id      pet_type    

  1            cat                     
  2            dog           
  3          rabbit
```

pet_symptoms

```
symptom_id       symptom        

  1          not playing         
  2          not eating
  3          not sleeping
 ...
```

Action_call

```
call_id      advice         

  1       take to vet         
  2       change food
  3       give a shower
 ...
```

I need my last page to pull session data from the first and second page to get (1) what the problem is with the pet and (2) what pet it is, in order to (3) give the correct advice.

here is my SQL on the 3rd page - calling vet

```
$rows=$db->query("SELECT call_id, advice pet_id, symptom_id, symptom, pet_type
        FROM pets, pet_symptoms, call_vet
        WHERE pets.pet_id = pet_symptoms.pet_id
        AND pets.pet_type='$_SESSION[pet_type]'
");
```

the problem I am having is that I want to see the problem as text and not an id on the second page, so I am not sure how to match the ids from different tables according to the problem selected.

thanks for any help

EDIT:

so that would look like

```
   id          pet_type                pet_symptom
    1            cat                  not sleeping
    2            dog                  not sleeping
```

.....

Comment: you need another table where u keep pet_id and symptom_id together.
keep this pets and pet_symptoms as master table.
in the new table you can have different pets with diff symptoms or symptoms repeated

Comment: `$_SESSION[pet_type]`, `pet_type` is being used as a constant. ~> `'{$_SESSION['pet_type']}'`

Comment: isnt it enough to have them like this?

Comment: pet and pet symptoms are master table as u can see they are root information. so create a new table where u store pet info and pet's symptom.

Comment: im trying to get the symptom as a generic set of symptoms and advice will be different for each pet, depending on what pet it is and the symptom together

Comment: ok i am going to edit my question to check if i understand what you are saying

Comment: can i double check this: the new master table should be used to store ALL possible outcomes (so for every single pet, and a record for each symptom), and the call_vet would reference this table??

Comment: yes. the new table will not be called as master table. this table should have pet_id, symptom_id and call_id.
so we can reference this ID with the other tables to see the definition of these IDs.

Comment: also u can add 1 more column to give a name to the Pet.

Comment: ok Sas, i will try that now.. thank you!!

Comment: can i just ask, if there are other columns in the call_vet table, like other questions to make sure, would they all be in the new master table too? (as in for every single possibility)?

Comment: also, would i still need the call_vet table? or will that table become redundant?

Comment: your call vet table should have distinct rows.
if u can see u have mentioned same reason for call_id 1 and 3. it should have different reason.

Comment: ok, if i manage to sort out the tables, can you please guide me with my SQL statement, i want to check whatever is saved in session (as the pet they have and the symptom the pet has - on two pages) and then give them a solution based on whats in the database!

Comment: in call_vet have only call_id and advices as of now. and create a table which will have all the info. only IDs , name of pet

Comment: sure go ahead..

Comment: i jus realised my call_vet table was supposed to have been that master table, imagine it has every pet listed and a symptom (using ids from the other tables - foreign keys), how would the third page call the id, based on the symptom (text version)? i am having difficulty mapping the correct id from the root table to the pet/symptom text

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Pet_health
(Pet_id number(3),
Pet_name Varchar2(15,)
Symptom_id number(3),
Call_id number(3))
```

Create this table. and this table will get the information from the other 3 table,
you do not have to UPDATE Pet, Pet Symptoms and Action call table unless u want to add new type of pet, new symptom and new advice. do not add duplicates.

Now Pet Health can have all the pets health issues

Once this is done then you can use this SELECT query

```
SELECT P.pet_type, PH.pet_name, S.symptom, A.advice  
FROM Pet_Health PH
INNER JOIN Pets P
ON PH.pet_id =P.pet_id
INNER JOIN Symptom S
ON PH.symptom_id = S.symptom_id
INNER JOIN Action_call A
ON PH.call_id = A.call_id
```

This query will show everything. if you want to show the ID, you can add it in `SELECT` statement

Comment: thats looking a lot better, only question now is, if in my website, i want a list of the symptoms, for the users to choose from, when they click on something, it should show the details (like the pet the selected and the issue). So, how does it link back to the id?

Comment: like for instance, the user clicks on cat > not sleeping, i want the database to search through the pets table to find id of cat, and match it to cat, then look through symptoms table and match not sleeping id with not sleeping, and then look through the new table pet health and match the cat id and symptom id and display all the following steps that are recommended.

Comment: ok thanks so much for your help! i will test that now and let you know!

Comment: Sure if you are satisfied with the answer then give a thumps up and mark it as answer. else u can always comment for more info :)

Comment: sure will do! is there any way for me to tag u on this chat, in case i have any further questions?